# Why does name property output nothing in the Edge browser when compressed?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, compression, minify

So I'm using a module that queries content based on its type and to figure out what content it is looking for, it must first build the query string by using various functions like Not, And, type, typeIs etc. One of these functions is causing me issues in production; Mainly the typeIs function. Here is how it is implemented.

```
 public typeIs<TNewType>(newTypeAssertion: new (...args: any[]) => TNewType) {
        this.stringValue = `TypeIs:${newTypeAssertion.name}` // Here is the issue
        this.segmentType = 'typeIs'
        return this.finialize<TNewType>()
 }
```

Now the problem with this is that when the code gets minified, by default all function names will get compressed, mangled etc. To solve this problem I set my minimizer to keep function names. Here is how it looks.

```
minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin({
      cache: true,
      parallel: true,
      terserOptions: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    })
]
```

This works great in chrome but the problem is that this doesn't work in edge.
Here is a screenshot to show what I mean.

[image: Edge browser unable to identify function name]

You can see that I've highlighted the word `Typeis:` in the image and the reason for this is because that is the part of the query string that is malformed. It should have been Typeis:User for it to work properly.

How I solved this isdue was by setting my minimizer to look like this:

```
minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin({
      cache: true,
      parallel: true,
      terserOptions: {
        keep_fnames: true,
        compress: false // This setting is crucial for it work on edge.
      }
    })
  ]
```

and now here is how it looks on Edge.

[image]

As you can see, now the query string is no longer malformed because there was no compression. Obviously I want my code to be compressed to lower my bundle size and have gone through many of its compress options to figure out which option is the culprit but to no avail.

My question is, why does the name property output nothing in the Edge browser when compressed and not in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The comment made by user `kzc` in this github issued helped me solved this problem(https://github.com/terser-js/terser/issues/120).

In his comment, he mentioned that it was a bug related to these 6 compression options

- `collapse_vars`
- `inline=3`
- `join_vars`
- `loops`
- `reduce_vars`
- `sequences (depending on the code)`
- `unused`

After finding that out, it was just matter of looking at the output bundle and making some logically deductions as to which one caused this issue. Turns out it was the reduce_vars option.

Now my minimizer looks like this

```
minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin({
      cache: true,
      parallel: true,
      terserOptions: {
        mangle: true,
        compress: {
          reduce_vars: false
        },
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    })
]
```

Looking at the terser documentation for its compression options, this is what reduce_vars does.

`reduce_vars` (default: `true`) -- Improve optimization on variables assigned with and used as constant values.

which makes sense as to why setting it to false solved this issue. At the top of the file my output bundle consisted of constant variables that hold references to modules that I imported and at some point in the compression stage, it reduced those variables so much that it probably couldn't figure out what module that variable belong to. That is just what I think and maybe someone else can chime in on this issue.